# Yield then convert to a list, or returning a list directly?

Tags: python, generator, yield

My current code is like this:

```
def generateRaw(self, word):
    for entry in self.entries:
        if word in html.unescape(etree.tostring(entry).decode('utf8')):
            yield xmltodict.parse(etree.tostring(entry))

def getRaw(self, word):
    return list(self.generateRaw(word))
```

Of course, I can just:-

```
def getRaw(self, word):
    result = []
    for entry in self.entries:
        if word in html.unescape(etree.tostring(entry).decode('utf8')):
            result += [xmltodict.parse(etree.tostring(entry))]
    return result
```

But, what is a good practice? What is a better way?

Also, recently, I find out that I can use a decorator to convert this, but I haven't really try it out yet:-

```
def iter2list(func):
    def wrapped(*args):
        return list(func(*args))
    return wrapped

@iter2list
...
```

I wonder if there is already a module to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is probably not,  unless someone has created a module which includes the function `iter2list`. A "module" solution in this case won't make the task easier or more efficient.

You've already identified two good ways of exhausting a generator in a single list.

I prefer the decorator method when the generator is designed to be exhausted when used, otherwise use `list(mygen())`. Syntactically, I find generators more readable, so I don't usually explicitly instantiate a list and fill it.